# Combining conditional classifier probabilities

Tags: probability, classification, conditional-probability

#### Context

I have several document classifiers trying to predict the correct document type for a document. For a given file, each classifier outputs a list of the probabilities of each document type. I'm trying to combine the predictions of these different classifiers into a single probability list.

I have two constraints:

1. I want to be able to manually decide and adjust how trusted / impactful every classifier will be towards the final prediction.
2. I don't really want to rely on a "training dataset" (my classifiers are mostly rule-based "expert systems"), so I want to combine them using a formula rather than ML ensembling / stacking techniques.

#### Basic approach

I started using a weighted average to combine the predictions.

If we look at an example with three classifiers (One, Two, Three) and three document types (T1, T2, T3). With the weighted average method, I would compute 
`Presult(T1) = (1 * Pone(T1) + 2 * Ptwo(T1) + 2 * Pthree(T1)) / (1 + 2 + 2) = 0.5`

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Classifier ║ Coefficient ║  P(T1)  ║  P(T2)  ║  P(T3)  ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ One        ║      1      ║   0.7   ║   0.1   ║   0.2   ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ Two        ║      2      ║   0.8   ║   0.0   ║   0.2   ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ Three      ║      2      ║   0.1   ║   0.2   ║   0.7   ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Results    ║      /      ║   0.5   ║   0.1   ║   0.4   ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

This simple approach seems to work, but things get more complicated.

#### The problem

In fact, some of my classifiers are specialized: they do no apply to the entire input domain (the full list of document types), but only to a subdomain. For example, I might have a classifier that, given an IRS form, can determine the respective probabilities of the document being a W-2, a W-3 or a 1040 form. In that case, the output probabilities are conditional probabilities.

Let's say that classifiers Two and Three are specialized classifiers. Classifier Two only apply to types T1 and T2, and classifier Three only applies to type T2 and T3. My new table could look something like this:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Classifier ║ Coefficient ║  P(T1)  ║  P(T2)  ║  P(T3)  ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ One        ║      1      ║   0.5   ║   0.3   ║   0.2   ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ Two        ║      2      ║   0.2   ║   0.8   ║   N/A   ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ Three      ║      2      ║   N/A   ║   0.4   ║   0.6   ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
╔════════════╦═════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Results    ║      /      ║    ?    ║    ?    ║    ?    ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

However, in that case, it does not really makes sense to use a weighted average to compute the final probabilities, because we would be adding probabilities on different domains. I've tried drafting several approaches but could not find anything adapted. Do you have any idea or pointers to existing methods to combine these different predictions into one?

Thank you for reading ;)

PS: I'm sorry for the lack of mathematical formalism of the question, but wasn't sure how to write it correctly. I'd be happy to rewrite it if it helps.

Comment: In a general sense, Bayesian inference might be a way to approach this problem. My favorite introduction is the short article by R.T. Cox, "Probability, Frequency, and Reasonable Expectation", American Journal of Physics vol 14, no. 1 (1946), which you can find on the web. Bear in mind that Bayesian inference is a very general approach; you would probably want to read up about that and then look for more specific resources.